# How to grant application permissions in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I want to run an application in Windows 7 that has application-specific access to files.  In other words, a user has permission to run the application, the application has permission open file X, but the user cannot use Windows Explorer (or any other applications) to open file X.

I assume the process is something like:

```
1. Create a group "Foo"
2. Create a folder with no permissions except to group Foo, put files in that folder
3. Make the application a member of group Foo
```

This should be trivial, but I haven't been able to ask Google the right question for adding an application to a group - all hits refer to either grouping icons together on the taskbar or adding users (not applications) to a group.   How do you assign group membership to an application in Windows 7?

Comment: If a user cannot open the file then the application has to be ran as a user that can access the file.  A program's permissions are limited to the user's permission that executed it.  Ths behavior is the entire concept of security within Windows.  You cannot assign specific permissions to an application only users.

Comment: This sounds incredibly insecure - there is really no analog of SUID/SGID in Windows that allows operators to do things under application control without giving those operators the ability to mess things up outside the application?

Comment: It actually is very secure.  It means that a process can only do what the user's permissions which ran it can do.  Its really no different then having to use `sudo` or "super do" which is basically the Unix/Linux variation of Windows "run as"

Comment: You misunderstand - SUID is nothing like sudo.   A user running an elevated Windows application can do essentially unlimited damage to the system.  A normal (limited) user running the identical application with application privileges doesn't need admin credentials as UAC or sudo would require, but the application would have the privileges necessary to accomplish its goal.   Least privilege is a fundamental security principle, and giving a single vetted application a set of privileges is more in line with that principle than giving a user the identical privileges usable with any application.

Comment: A commenter in "http://superuser.com/questions/432527/how-to-give-an-application-limited-permissions-on-windows-7" gets it:

There are solutions like "Bufferzone" to sandbox applications ... but no way (that I know of) to tick off "this program has access to registry and file system, but not networking" or something like that. Might be a neat feature to have, though. –  aikeru Jun 8 '12 at 14:43

Comment: Your last comment has a typo in it, but I fully understand, there is no misunderstanding on my end

Answer (score 0):

I've got a media server that can no longer notice new files added to the existing directory structure. My windows user (the one I am logged in with) can see and directly use the files in Explorer. But the application can't see the files though I have Admin acces. So aparently applications can have permissions that are lesser than the user, just not more.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1168517)